# Converting items in the list in the dataframe column to the string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe containing list in the column

```
item list      
['ABC','PQR']  
['DEF']        
[]
```

I want to add another column called "item".which contains the corresponding string to that list

```
item list      item   
['ABC','PQR']  ABC,PQR
['DEF']        DEF
[]
```

I have tried the following

```
df["item"]=df["item list"].apply(lambda x:",".join(x))
```

but it's giving me wrong answer like th following

```
item list      item   
['ABC','PQR']  A,B,C,P,Q,R
['DEF']        D,E,F
[]
```

I need to get the follwoing answer.How can I achieve it?

```
item list      item   
['ABC','PQR']  ABC,PQR
['DEF']        DEF
[]
```

Comment: `df["item list"].str.join(',')` ?

Comment: anky just pointed the right way to do it, but there is probably something else. Your code actually works fine on this data, so probably you need to check column values are actually lists

Comment: @Marat Good one, I missed it, may be `ast.literal_eval` can help in that case: `df1['item list'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(ast.literal_eval(x)))`